# How can I uniquely identify which device is on USB `hub 6-0:1.0: port 2`?

Tags: linux, usb, devices

How can I uniquely identify which device is on USB `hub 6-0:1.0: port 2`?

I receive messages in my `dmesg` every now and then and I want the system to tell me which device is connected to that port.

**EDIT:** OK, I can figure out which hub it is, but how can I figure out which device is on port 2 (out of four).

```
udevadm info -q all -p /sys/bus/usb/devices/6-0:1.0
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-0:1.0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-0:1.0
E: DEVTYPE=usb_interface
E: DRIVER=hub
E: INTERFACE=9/0/0
E: MODALIAS=usb:v1D6Bp0001d0302dc09dsc00dp00ic09isc00ip00
E: PRODUCT=1d6b/1/302
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: TYPE=9/0/0
E: UDEV_LOG=3
```

Comment: [This blog post seems related, the author's written a python script to cast light onto complicated topologies](http://www.jonnor.com/2010/08/determining-physical-topology-of-hotplugged-usb-devices-with-udev/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any utility that can give you this information directly, but you can get it by using a few different utilities.

**Shortest route:**

```
udevadm info -q all -p /sys/bus/usb/devices/6-0:1.0
```

This will give you output of which one of the lines will look like the following (obviously this output won't match your system):

```
E: DEVICE=/proc/bus/usb/006/053
```

Then run `lsusb` and look for the device at `Bus 006` `Device 053` (from the `006/053` in the above line), this will be your device.

.

For more info, you can poke around in that `/sys/bus/usb/devices/6-0:1.0` if you want. You can also change the `udevadm` command to `udevadm info -a -p ...` instead which will walk up the udev tree.

Comment: Added my comment to the question. With your help I am able to figure out that 6-0:1.0 is a hub, but what's on port 2?

Comment: @jippie are you sure the problem isnt with the hub? Each device on the hub gets its own device ID, so if the device has a problem, it *should* give you the device ID of the device having the problem.

Comment: Starting to look like it indeed.

Comment: Changed the cabling to the hub, haven´ t had problems **yet**