# How to find the device is connected to which usb hub in linux OS?

Tags: linux, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I uniquely identify which device is on USB `hub 6-0:1.0: port 2`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38121/how-can-i-uniquely-identify-which-device-is-on-usb-hub-6-01-0-port-2)

I connected three USB hub in a system and I connected different devices in each hub. How I can find which device is connected to each hub? Is it possible with lsusb command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take look at the `dmesg` output after you connecting the USB device to the hub. It will tell you which USB hub (/dev/NODE_NAME) is which device.

Comment: Where this informations are located in hard disk.
I found new files are creating in "/dev" dir and in "/sys/bus/usb/" etc.., when I connected a new device in hub is there any easy way to find it from there?. That is useful to my program

Comment: `dmesg` output will tell you where your USB hub info files and etc. are being located ;)